# Expressao regular para pegar link Youtube em texto

Tags: php, regex

Tenho um texto no wordpress e nesse texto tem um link para youtube:

> Saúde" todas as segundas-feiras, às 9h15, com reprise às
>   sextas-feiras, a partir das 13 horas.
>
> Durante a exibição da
>   atração, a apresentadora costuma receber profissionais da saúde para
>   dar dicas de alimentação, medicação, postura e qualidade de vida aos
>   telespectadores.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNR3lGyiLQA
>
> **Breve histórico da apresentadora:** Gisela Savioli foi a nutricionista
>   responsável pela alimentação dos

criei esse expressa, mas nao está dando certo, ainda está vindo null, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
public function getUrlFromContent($content){
    $video_url=null;
    $pattern = '/(youtu|y2u)(be)?\.(com|be)(\.br)?\/(watch\?v=)?[^"\&\?\/ ]{11}/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $result_youtube);
    if (isset($result_youtube[0])) {  
        $video_url = "http://" . $result_youtube[0];
    }
    return $video_url;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou a resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que isso pode ajudar, basicamente, alterei o $pattern.

```
<?php

$content = 'Saúde" todas as segundas-feiras, às 9h15, com reprise às sextas-feiras, a partir das 13 horas.

Durante a exibição da atração, a apresentadora costuma receber profissionais da saúde para dar dicas de alimentação, medicação, postura e qualidade de vida aos telespectadores.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNR3lGyiLQA

Breve histórico da apresentadora: Gisela Savioli foi a nutricionista responsável pela alimentação dos';



function getUrlFromContent($content){
    $video_url=null;
    $pattern = '~http(s){0,1}://(www.){0,1}(youtube.com/watch\?v=|y2u.be/|youtu.be/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}~';
    // $pattern = '/(youtu|y2u)(be)?\.(com|be)(\.br)?\/(watch\?v=)?[^"\&\?\/ ]{11}/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $result_youtube);
    if (isset($result_youtube[0])) {  
        $video_url = $result_youtube[0];
    }
    return $video_url;
}


echo getUrlFromContent($content);
```

OBS: Editei para aceitar também [links resumidos do Youtube](http://y2u.be/).

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Como eu não sei se o link vai vir sempre com quebra de linha ao final defini que o tamanha da `string` que define o video tera entre 8 e 11 caracteres.

```
 ((https?:\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?\w=.{8,11})
```

Desta forma fica opcional entre :

- https://www.youtube.com
- http://www.youtube.com
- www.youtube.com

Caso tenha quebra de linha ou espaço apos o link.

```
((https?:\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?\w=[^ \n]+)
```